# CsQuery remove comments

Tags: c#, html, csquery

I'm getting a URL and get all of it's content by calling:

```
CQ dom = ...;
string content = dom.Text();
```

I'm noticed that the "Text()" method also extracting HTML comments like:

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- This is comment - Ignore me -->
</body>
</html>
```

I looking for some option to remove all those comments from code. Something like this:

```
dom["comment"].remove();
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution.

The creation of the dom should be done like this:

```
CQ.Create(stream, Encoding.UTF8, HtmlParsingMode.Auto, HtmlParsingOptions.IgnoreComments);
```

**HtmlParsingOptions.IgnoreComments** was what I'm looking for.